# Проблемы пошаговой прокрутки слайдера

Tags: jquery, slider

Не получается задать прокрутку слайдера по шагам

```
$('.ctrls').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        slide = $('.slider-wrapper'),
        currentPosition = slide.attr('left');
    if($this.hasClass('next')) {
        slide.animate({left: currentPosition + "-100%"})
    }
    if($this.hasClass('prev')) {
        slide.animate({left: currentPosition + "100%"})
    }
});
```

Comment: Для получения ответа рекомендую разместить на любом ресурсе для отладки в вебе, типа того же доджо телерика.

Comment: А зачем перед именем переменной this стоит $ ? Сами-то не путаетесь  ?

Comment: IDEшка ругается если убрать $